# Firebase JSON import error

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import a **JSON** file to **firebase** but getting error saying that the keys cannot contain special characters. I have already gone through the data and sure that the keys doesn't have any **prohibited characters**. Eg: **[,],#,$,.**
I have also removed any **duplicate keys** in the data. Also tried using **UTF-8** encoding. But still the same error. This is the link to the JSON data file.
Tested in all JSON validation sites like **Prolintjson , jsonfomatter** and many others. The result was "valid JSON" file but unable to import to firebase.

**Link:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6QAOtGfpMYad3l1a2c2WHZONEk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorted out. There was key with "\n" carriage return. Now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out. There was key with "\n" carriage return. Now working fine.